# What exactly is kqueue's EV_RECEIPT for?

Tags: macos, freebsd, kqueue

The [kqueue mechanism](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kqueue&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.3-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html) has an event flag, `EV_RECEIPT`, which according to the linked man page:

> ... is useful for making bulk changes to a kqueue
>             without draining any pending events.  When passed as input,
>             it forces `EV_ERROR` to   always be returned.  When a filter is
>             successfully added the data field will be zero.

My understanding however is that it is trivial to make bulk changes to a kqueue without draining any pending events, simply by passing 0 for the `nevents` parameter to `kevent` and thus drawing no events from the queue. With that in mind, why is `EV_RECEIPT` necesary?

Some [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2050/_index.html) in Apple documentation for OS X actually uses EV_RECEIPT:

```
kq = kqueue();

EV_SET(&changes, gTargetPID, EVFILT_PROC, EV_ADD | EV_RECEIPT, NOTE_EXIT, 0, NULL);
(void) kevent(kq, &changes, 1, &changes, 1, NULL);
```

But, seeing as the `changes` array is never examined after the `kevent` call, it's totally unclear to me why `EV_RECEIPT` was used in this case.

**Is EV_RECEIPT actually necessary? In what situation would it really be useful?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are making bulk changes and one of them causes an error, then the event will be placed in the `eventlist` with EV_ERROR set in `flags` and the system error in `data`.

Therefore it is possible to identify which `changelist` element caused the error.

If you set `nevents` to zero, you get the error code but no indication of which event caused the error.

So EV_RECEIPT allows you to set `nevents` to a non-zero value without draining any pending events.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense, but it doesn't correlate with the code in the Apple example that I linked. The comment in that code says: _Create the kqueue and set it up to watch for SIGCHLD. Use the  new-in-10.5 EV_RECEIPT flag to ensure that we get what we expect_ - however, it calls `kevent` with just a single event, uses `EV_RECEIPT`, and checks neither the return from `kevent` nor the values in the return events. Any clue as to what the comment means by "we get what we expect"? - or is the use of `EV_RECEIPT` in this case bogus?

Comment: I think in this case, setting `nevents` to zero would achieve identical behaviour, as the return value is not checked. But this may be a pattern that is replicated in other code where the return value *is* checked. The expectation being that the new filter is returned and *not* a pending event.

Comment: Is this code even entirely valid then, since it does not check the events list for errors? I seemed to be discovering that zombie processes return ESRCH when you try to add them to kqevent with NOTE_EXIT, but I cannot find many references or documentation online that describe what is supposed to happen in that case.